# Отрисовка текстурированого куба

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, opengl, graphics

В поисках более быстрого рендера столкнулся с VBO а если точней с glDrawElements()

И вроде построил куб но вод текстура полностью накладываться отказывается наблюдаю такую картину текстурируются только 2 стороны Передняя(Front) и задняя(Back) [image: Ошибка наложение текстур]

**Чем инициализирую VBO**

```
    void initVertexDataV2()
    {
        VertexDataV2[0].x=1.0;   VertexDataV2[0].y=1.0;   VertexDataV2[0].z=1.0;
        VertexDataV2[1].x=-1.0;  VertexDataV2[1].y=1.0;   VertexDataV2[1].z=1.0;
        VertexDataV2[2].x=-1.0;  VertexDataV2[2].y=-1.0;  VertexDataV2[2].z=1.0;
        VertexDataV2[3].x=1.0;   VertexDataV2[3].y=-1.0;  VertexDataV2[3].z=1.0;

        VertexDataV2[4].x=1.0;   VertexDataV2[4].y=1.0;   VertexDataV2[4].z=-1.0;
        VertexDataV2[5].x=-1.0;  VertexDataV2[5].y=1.0;   VertexDataV2[5].z=-1.0;
        VertexDataV2[6].x=-1.0;  VertexDataV2[6].y=-1.0;  VertexDataV2[6].z=-1.0;
        VertexDataV2[7].x=1.0;   VertexDataV2[7].y=-1.0;  VertexDataV2[7].z=-1.0;

    }
void initTextureDataV2()
    {
   ///Front/////////////////////////////////////////
    TextureDataV2[0].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[0].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[1].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[1].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[2].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[2].v = 0.0f;
    TextureDataV2[3].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[3].v = 0.0f;
     ///Back//////////////////////////////////////////
    TextureDataV2[4].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[4].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[5].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[5].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[6].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[6].v = 0.0f;
    TextureDataV2[7].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[7].v = 0.0f;
    ///Left/////////////////////////////////////////////
    TextureDataV2[8].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[8].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[9].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[9].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[10].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[10].v = 0.0f;
    TextureDataV2[11].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[11].v = 0.0f;
     ///Right////////////////////////////////////////////
    TextureDataV2[12].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[12].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[13].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[13].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[14].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[14].v = 0.0f;
    TextureDataV2[15].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[15].v = 0.0f;
    ///Top/////////////////////////////////////////////
    TextureDataV2[16].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[16].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[17].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[17].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[18].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[18].v = 0.0f;
    TextureDataV2[19].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[19].v = 0.0f;
    ///Down//////////////////////////////////////////////
    TextureDataV2[20].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[20].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[21].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[21].v = 1.0f;
    TextureDataV2[22].u = 1.0f; TextureDataV2[22].v = 0.0f;
    TextureDataV2[23].u = 0.0f; TextureDataV2[23].v = 0.0f;
    }

void initIndexDataV2()
    {
      ///Front/////////////////////////////////////////
        IndexDataV2[0] = 0;
        IndexDataV2[1] = 1;
        IndexDataV2[2] = 2;

        IndexDataV2[3] = 2;
        IndexDataV2[4] = 3;
        IndexDataV2[5] = 0;
        ///Back//////////////////////////////////////////
        IndexDataV2[6] = 4;
        IndexDataV2[7] = 5;
        IndexDataV2[8] = 6;

        IndexDataV2[9] = 6;
        IndexDataV2[10] = 7;
        IndexDataV2[11] = 4;
        ///Left/////////////////////////////////////////////
        IndexDataV2[12] = 4;
        IndexDataV2[13] = 0;
        IndexDataV2[14] = 3;

        IndexDataV2[15] = 3;
        IndexDataV2[16] = 7;
        IndexDataV2[17] = 4;
        ///Right////////////////////////////////////////////
        IndexDataV2[18] = 5;
        IndexDataV2[19] = 1;
        IndexDataV2[20] = 2;

        IndexDataV2[21] = 2;
        IndexDataV2[22] = 6;
        IndexDataV2[23] = 5;
        ///Top/////////////////////////////////////////////
        IndexDataV2[24] = 4;
        IndexDataV2[25] = 5;
        IndexDataV2[26] = 1;

        IndexDataV2[27] = 1;
        IndexDataV2[28] = 0;
        IndexDataV2[29] = 4;
        ///Down//////////////////////////////////////////////
        IndexDataV2[30] = 7;
        IndexDataV2[31] = 6;
        IndexDataV2[32] = 2;

        IndexDataV2[33] = 2;
        IndexDataV2[34] = 3;
        IndexDataV2[35] = 7;
```

**Процесс построения VBO**

```
glBindTexture(0,texture[0]);

TestVBO.FillingVertexBuffer(VertexDataV2,8);
TestVBO.FillingTextureBuffer(TextureDataV2,24);
TestVBO.FillingIndexBuffer(IndexDataV2,36);
TestVBO.InitVertex();
TestVBO.InitTexture();
TestVBO.InitIndex();

TestVBO.Render();
```

**Класс работы с VBO**

```
class VBOv2
{

    public:

    GLuint idVertexVBO;
    GLuint idTextureVBO;
    GLuint idIndexVBO;
    GLboolean Ready; //Готов к рендерингу ?
    std::vector <Vector3f> VertexBuffer;
    std::vector <GLuint> IndexBuffer;
    std::vector <Texture2f> TextureBuffer;

    VBOv2()
    {
       idVertexVBO = 0 ;
       idTextureVBO= 0 ;
       idIndexVBO  = 0 ;
       Ready = GL_FALSE ; //false
    };

    void InitVertex();

    void InitIndex();

    void InitTexture();

    void FillingVertexBuffer(Vector3f CopyArr[],GLint SizeVector);

    void FillingIndexBuffer(GLuint CopyArr[],GLuint SizeVector);

    void FillingTextureBuffer(Texture2f CopyArr[],GLint SizeVector);

    void Render();

};

void VBOv2::InitVertex()
    {
        glewInit();

        //Создание нового VBO и сохранение идентификатора VBO
        glGenBuffers(1, &idVertexVBO);

        //Установка активности VBO
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, idVertexVBO);

        //Выгрузка данных вершин в видеоустройство
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VertexBuffer.size()*sizeof(float)*3, &VertexBuffer[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        /*в качестве второго параметра мы задаем размер данного буфера в байтах.*/

        //Рисование треугольника из VBO - происходит каждый раз, когда окно, точка обзора или данные изменяются
        //Устанавливаем 3 координаты каждой вершины с 0 шагом в этом массиве; тут необходимо
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

        //Данный массив содержит вершины(не нормалей, цвета, текстуры и т.д.)
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    }

    void VBOv2::InitIndex()
    {
      glGenBuffers( 1, &idIndexVBO );
      glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, idIndexVBO);
      glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * IndexBuffer.size(), &IndexBuffer[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    void VBOv2::InitTexture()
    {

    //Создание нового VBO и сохранение идентификатора VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &idTextureVBO);

    //Установка активности VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, idTextureVBO);

    //Выгрузка данных текстур в видеоустройство
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,TextureBuffer.size()*sizeof(float)*2, &TextureBuffer[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    /*в качестве второго параметра мы задаем размер данного буфера в байтах.*/

    glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,NULL);

    //Данный массив содержит(текстуры)
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    }
//#include <stdio.h>//Debug
    void VBOv2::FillingVertexBuffer(Vector3f CopyArr[],GLint SizeVector)
    {
        for(GLint i(0);i<SizeVector;)
        {
        VertexBuffer.push_back(Vector3f());
        VertexBuffer[i].x = CopyArr[i].x;
        VertexBuffer[i].y = CopyArr[i].y;
        VertexBuffer[i].z = CopyArr[i].z;
       /// printf("%f %f %f \n",VertexBuffer[i].x,VertexBuffer[i].y,VertexBuffer[i].z); //Debug
        i++;
        }

    };

    void VBOv2::FillingTextureBuffer(Texture2f CopyArr[],GLint SizeVector)
    {
        for(GLint i(0);i<SizeVector;)
        {
        TextureBuffer.push_back(Texture2f());
        TextureBuffer[i].u = CopyArr[i].u;
        TextureBuffer[i].v = CopyArr[i].v;
        //printf("%f %f  \n",TextureBuffer[i].u,TextureBuffer[i].v); //Debug
        i++;
        }

    };

    void VBOv2::FillingIndexBuffer(GLuint CopyArr[],GLuint SizeVector)
    {
        for(GLuint i(0);i<SizeVector;i++)
        {
            IndexBuffer.push_back(GLuint());
            IndexBuffer[i] = CopyArr[i];
        }

    }

    void VBOv2::Render()
    {
    glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, idIndexVBO);
    //Рисование треугольника, указывая количества вершин
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,IndexBuffer.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,NULL);//sizeof(float) / 3

    glPopMatrix();
    glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT);

    };
```

Comment: в `initTextureDataV2()` не пробовали поиграться с текстурными координатами?

Comment: Не поверите играю с ними уже 2 сутки =(

Comment: А почему у вас в `glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,NULL);` первый параметр 2, а не 4 например?

Comment: Насколько я понял это количество Координат так как текстура плоская использую 2D представление UV  то есть 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Боюсь, Вы не верно понимаете использование функции glDrawElements.
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml
Ее смысл в том, что вы указываете массив координат и массив номеров вертексов для построения выбранным способом.

В Вашем случае логичнее использовать glDrawArrays. Попробуйте, по идее, проблема должна решится.

**UPDATE:**

Для куба ABCDEFGH текстурные координаты должны выглядеть как-то так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но тут проблема с верхней и нижней гранями.

Попробуйте использовать GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP.
http://programming4.us/multimedia/3782.aspx
http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial25/tutorial25.html

Comment: Прикол в том что у Меня прекрасно получается вывод с помощью  glDrawArrays просто хочется разобраться .

Comment: glDrawElements нужен когда у Вас есть просто список координат вершин, а для их отрисовки в нужной последовательности используется отдельный массив с их номерами. То есть для отрисовки квадрата a-b-c-d посредством GL_TRIANGLES вам нужно в этом массиве индексов указать следующее: 0 (a), 1(b), 2(c), 1(b), 2(c), 3(d). Это удобно, когда для каждой вершины требуется много информации и дублирование нежелательно.

Comment: это то ясно я строил куб по 8 координатам и 6(Граней)*6(Количество точек в двух треугольников для полигона)=36 индексам но ловил вот такой артефакт с текстурой

Comment: логично, потому что когда Вы указываете координаты для текстуры, это по сути точки, которые цепляются за вершины. Текстурные координаты тоже атрибут вершины. При использовании glDrawElements количество всех атрибутов должно совпадать. Сейчас залью картинку в ответ

Comment: Попробуйте использовать GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP.

Comment: Как всё запутано...
Пойду переваривать...
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Переписал входные значения всё гуд

```
void initVertexDataV2()
{
// Top
VertexDataV2[0].x        = 1;    VertexDataV2[0].y        = 1;    VertexDataV2[0].z        = -1;
VertexDataV2[1].x        = -1;   VertexDataV2[1].y        = 1;    VertexDataV2[1].z        = -1;
VertexDataV2[2].x        = -1;   VertexDataV2[2].y        = 1;    VertexDataV2[2].z        = 1;
VertexDataV2[3].x        = 1;    VertexDataV2[3].y        = 1;    VertexDataV2[3].z        = 1;
// Bottom
VertexDataV2[4].x        = 1;    VertexDataV2[4].y        = -1;   VertexDataV2[4].z        = 1;
VertexDataV2[5].x        = -1;   VertexDataV2[5].y        = -1;   VertexDataV2[5].z        = 1;
VertexDataV2[6].x        = -1;   VertexDataV2[6].y        = -1;   VertexDataV2[6].z        = -1;
VertexDataV2[7].x        = 1;    VertexDataV2[7].y        = -1;   VertexDataV2[7].z        = -1;
// Front
VertexDataV2[8].x        = 1;    VertexDataV2[8].y        = 1;    VertexDataV2[8].z        = 1;
VertexDataV2[9].x        = -1;   VertexDataV2[9].y        = 1;    VertexDataV2[9].z        = 1;
VertexDataV2[10].x       = -1;   VertexDataV2[10].y       = -1;   VertexDataV2[10].z       = 1;
VertexDataV2[11].x       = 1;    VertexDataV2[11].y       = -1;   VertexDataV2[11].z       = 1;
// Back
VertexDataV2[12].x       = 1;    VertexDataV2[12].y       = -1;   VertexDataV2[12].z       = -1;
VertexDataV2[13].x       = -1;   VertexDataV2[13].y       = -1;   VertexDataV2[13].z       = -1;
VertexDataV2[14].x       = -1;   VertexDataV2[14].y       = 1;    VertexDataV2[14].z       = -1;
VertexDataV2[15].x       = 1;    VertexDataV2[15].y       = 1;    VertexDataV2[15].z       = -1;
// Left
VertexDataV2[16].x       = -1;   VertexDataV2[16].y       = 1;    VertexDataV2[16].z       = 1;
VertexDataV2[17].x       = -1;   VertexDataV2[17].y       = 1;    VertexDataV2[17].z       = -1;
VertexDataV2[18].x       = -1;   VertexDataV2[18].y       = -1;   VertexDataV2[18].z       = -1;
VertexDataV2[19].x       = -1;   VertexDataV2[19].y       = -1;   VertexDataV2[19].z       = 1;
// Right
VertexDataV2[20].x       = 1;    VertexDataV2[20].y       = 1;    VertexDataV2[20].z       = -1;
VertexDataV2[21].x       = 1;    VertexDataV2[21].y       = 1;    VertexDataV2[21].z       = 1;
VertexDataV2[22].x       = 1;    VertexDataV2[22].y       = -1;   VertexDataV2[22].z       = 1;
VertexDataV2[23].x       = 1;    VertexDataV2[23].y       = -1;   VertexDataV2[23].z       = -1;
}

void initTextureDataV2()
{
// Top
TextureDataV2[0].u             = 0;    TextureDataV2[0].v       = 0;
TextureDataV2[1].u             = 0;    TextureDataV2[1].v       = 1;
TextureDataV2[2].u             = 1;    TextureDataV2[2].v       = 1;
TextureDataV2[3].u             = 1;    TextureDataV2[3].v       = 0;
// Bottom
TextureDataV2[4].u             = 0;    TextureDataV2[4].v       = 0;
TextureDataV2[5].u             = 0;    TextureDataV2[5].v       = 1;
TextureDataV2[6].u             = 1;    TextureDataV2[6].v       = 1;
TextureDataV2[7].u             = 1;    TextureDataV2[7].v       = 0;
// Front
TextureDataV2[8].u             = 0;    TextureDataV2[8].v       = 0;
TextureDataV2[9].u             = 0;    TextureDataV2[9].v       = 1;
TextureDataV2[10].u            = 1;    TextureDataV2[10].v      = 1;
TextureDataV2[11].u            = 1;    TextureDataV2[11].v      = 0;
// Back
TextureDataV2[12].u            = 0;    TextureDataV2[12].v            = 0;
TextureDataV2[13].u            = 0;    TextureDataV2[13].v            = 1;
TextureDataV2[14].u            = 1;    TextureDataV2[14].v            = 1;
TextureDataV2[15].u            = 1;    TextureDataV2[15].v            = 0;
// Left
TextureDataV2[16].u            = 0;    TextureDataV2[16].v            = 0;
TextureDataV2[17].u            = 0;    TextureDataV2[17].v            = 1;
TextureDataV2[18].u            = 1;    TextureDataV2[18].v            = 1;
TextureDataV2[19].u            = 1;    TextureDataV2[19].v            = 0;
// Right
TextureDataV2[20].u            = 0;    TextureDataV2[20].v            = 0;
TextureDataV2[21].u            = 0;    TextureDataV2[21].v            = 1;
TextureDataV2[22].u            = 1;    TextureDataV2[22].v            = 1;
TextureDataV2[23].u            = 1;    TextureDataV2[23].v            = 0;
}

void initIndexDataV2()
{
    // 1      2
    // +------+
    // |      |
    // |      |
    // +------+
    // 0      3
    IndexDataV2[0] = 0;   IndexDataV2[1] = 1;   IndexDataV2[2] = 2;
    IndexDataV2[3] = 2;   IndexDataV2[4] = 3;   IndexDataV2[5] = 0;

    IndexDataV2[6] = 4;   IndexDataV2[7] = 5;   IndexDataV2[8] = 6;
    IndexDataV2[9] = 6;   IndexDataV2[10] = 7;  IndexDataV2[11] = 4;

    IndexDataV2[12] = 8;  IndexDataV2[13] = 9;  IndexDataV2[14] = 10;
    IndexDataV2[15] = 10; IndexDataV2[16] = 11; IndexDataV2[17] = 8;

    IndexDataV2[18] = 12; IndexDataV2[19] = 13; IndexDataV2[20] = 14;
    IndexDataV2[21] = 14; IndexDataV2[22] = 15; IndexDataV2[23] = 12;

    IndexDataV2[24] = 16; IndexDataV2[25] = 17; IndexDataV2[26] = 18;
    IndexDataV2[27] = 18; IndexDataV2[28] = 19; IndexDataV2[29] = 16;

    IndexDataV2[30] = 20; IndexDataV2[31] = 21; IndexDataV2[32] = 22;
    IndexDataV2[33] = 22; IndexDataV2[34] = 23; IndexDataV2[35] = 20;
}
```